# Wordpress- Display items in order

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress installation with a "meet our team" section, which is great, but there is no way to rank them in any kind of order. I just finished school for php in December and I, not the greatest at it. I know I'm so close but I've just been staring for like 2 hours. Does anyone know how to write php to make it so the team members are listed in an order that I specify somehow? Thanks so much for any help anyone can provide I'm starting to get desperate.

```
<?php

//Condition for Parent Class

if(class_exists('function_library')){



add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'team_fun_override' );

function team_fun_override() {

    $team_class = new cp_team_class;

}



class cp_team_class extends function_library{

    public $team_array = array(



        'image_icon' =>array(



            'type'=> 'image',



            'name'=> 'aa',



            'hr'=> 'none',



            'description'=> "fa fa-user"),



        "top-bar-div33-open" => array( 'name'=>'div_start','type'=>'open' ,'class'=>'row-fluid','id'=>'cp-top-bar-div33'),  



        'header'=>array(



            'title'=> 'TEAM HEADER TITLE',



            'name'=> 'page-option-item-team-header-title',



            'type'=> 'inputtext'),



        'category'=>array(



            'title'=>'CHOOSE CATEGORY',



            'name'=>'page-option-category-team',



            'options'=>array(),



            'type'=>'combobox_category',



            'hr'=> 'none',



            'description'=>'Choose the team category you want the members to be fetched.'),     



        'num_excerpt'=>array(



            'title'=>'NUMBER OF EXCERPT',



            'name'=>'page-option-item-team-excerpt',



            'type'=> 'inputtext',



            'default'=> 200,



            'description'=>'Number of words to show on team member.'),



        "top-bar-div33-close" => array( 'name'=>'div_end','type'=>'close','id'=>'cp-top-bar-div33'),        



        "top-bar-div34-open" => array( 'name'=>'div_start','type'=>'open' ,'class'=>'row-fluid','id'=>'cp-top-bar-div34'),  



        'pagination'=>array(



            'title'=>'ENABLE ORDER',



            'name'=>'page-option-item-team-pagination',



            'type'=> 'combobox',



            'options'=>array('0'=>'0', '1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3', '4'=>'4','5'=>'5', '6'=>'6', '7'=>'7'),



            'hr'=> 'none',



            'description'=>'Pick a number and hopefully this works and puts everybody in order.'),



        'num-fetch'=>array(                 



            'title'=> 'NUM OF MEMBERS',



            'name'=> 'page-option-item-team-num-fetch',



            'type'=> 'inputtext',



            'class'=>'team-fetch-member',



            'default'=> 9,



            'description'=>'Set the number of team members to display on one page.'),



        "top-bar-div34-close" => array( 'name'=>'div_end','type'=>'close','id'=>'cp-top-bar-div34'),            





    );





    public $team_size_array =  array('element1-1'=>'1/1');          



    public function page_builder_size_class(){

    global $div_size;

        $div_size['Our-Team'] = $this->team_size_array;   

    }



    public function page_builder_element_class(){

    global $page_meta_boxes;

        $page_meta_boxes['Page Item']['name']['Our-Team'] = $this->team_array;

        //$page_meta_boxes['Page Item']['name']['Our-Team']['select_feature']['options'] = function_library::get_title_list_array( 'teams' );   

        $page_meta_boxes['Page Item']['name']['Our-Team']['category']['options'] = function_library::get_category_list_array( 'team-category' );



    }



    public function __construct(){

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_ourteam' ) );

        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_team_option' ) );

        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_team_option_meta' ) );

    }









    public function create_ourteam() {

        //$portfolio_translation = get_option(THEME_NAME_S.'_cp_portfolio_slug','portfolio');



        $labels = array(

            'name' => _x('Our Team', 'Our Team General Name', 'crunchpress'),

            'singular_name' => _x('Our Team', 'Event Singular Name', 'crunchpress'),

            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Add New Our Team Name', 'crunchpress'),

            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Our Team', 'crunchpress'),

            'edit_item' => __('Edit Our Team', 'crunchpress'),

            'new_item' => __('New Our Team', 'crunchpress'),

            'view_item' => __('View Our Team', 'crunchpress'),

            'search_items' => __('Search Our Team', 'crunchpress'),

            'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found', 'crunchpress'),

            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', 'crunchpress'),

            'parent_item_colon' => ''

        );



        $args = array(

            'labels' => $labels,

            'public' => true,

            'publicly_queryable' => true,

            'show_ui' => true,

            'query_var' => true,

            'menu_icon' => '',

            'rewrite' => true,

            'capability_type' => 'post',

            'hierarchical' => false,

            'menu_position' => 100,

            'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments'),

            'has_archive' => true,

            'rewrite' => array('wi' => '', 'with_front' => false)

          ); 



        register_post_type( 'team' , $args);    



        register_taxonomy(

            "team-category", array("team"), array(

                "hierarchical" => true,

                "label" => "Team Categories", 

                "singular_label" => "Team Categories", 

                "rewrite" => true));

        register_taxonomy_for_object_type('team-category', 'team');         

    }







    public function add_team_option(){  



        add_meta_box('team-option', __('Our Team Options','crunchpress'), array($this,'add_our_team_element'),

            'team', 'normal', 'high');



    }

    public function add_our_team_element(){

        $team_social = '';

        $sidebar_team = '';

        $right_sidebar_team = '';

        $left_sidebar_team = '';

        $team_designation = '';

        $team_facebook = '';

        $team_linkedin = '';

        $team_twitter = '';







    foreach($_REQUEST as $keys=>$values){

        $$keys = $values;

    }

    global $post;





    $team_detail_xml = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'team_detail_xml', true);

    if($team_detail_xml <> ''){

        $cp_team_xml = new DOMDocument ();

        $cp_team_xml->loadXML ( $team_detail_xml );

        $team_social = function_library::find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'team_social');

        $sidebar_team = function_library::find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'sidebar_team');

        $left_sidebar_team = function_library::find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'left_sidebar_team');

        $right_sidebar_team = function_library::find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'right_sidebar_team');

        $team_designation = function_library::find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'team_designation');

        $team_facebook = function_library::find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'team_facebook');

        $team_linkedin = function_library::find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'team_linkedin');

        $team_twitter = function_library::find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'team_twitter');

    }

    ?>

    <div class="event_options">

        <div class="op-gap">

            <ul class="panel-body recipe_class row-fluid">

                <li class="panel-input span12">

                    <span class="panel-title">

                        <h3 for="team_social" > <?php _e('SOCIAL NETWORKING', 'crunchpress'); ?> </h3>

                    </span> 



                    <label for="team_social"><div class="checkbox-switch <?php



                    echo ($team_social=='enable' || ($team_social=='' && empty($default)))? 'checkbox-switch-on': 'checkbox-switch-off'; 



                ?>"></div></label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="team_social" class="checkbox-switch" value="disable" checked>

                <input type="checkbox" name="team_social" id="team_social" class="checkbox-switch" value="enable" <?php 



                    echo ($team_social=='enable' || ($team_social=='' && empty($default)))? 'checked': ''; 



                ?>>

                <p><?php _e('Turn On/Off Social Sharing on Team Detail.', 'crunchpress'); ?></p>

                </li>



            </ul>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php echo function_library::show_sidebar($sidebar_team,'right_sidebar_team','left_sidebar_team',$right_sidebar_team,$left_sidebar_team);?>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="row-fluid">

                <div class="span3">

                    <ul class="panel-body recipe_class">

                        <li class="panel-input">

                            <span class="panel-title">

                                <h3 for="team_designation" > <?php _e('DESIGNATION', 'crunchpress'); ?> </h3>

                            </span>

                            <input type="text" name="team_designation" id="team_designation" value="<?php if($team_designation <> ''){echo $team_designation;};?>" />

                            <p><?php _e('Please Enter Here Designation of the person.', 'crunchpress'); ?></p>

                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="span3">

                    <ul class="panel-body recipe_class">

                        <li class="panel-title">

                            <h3 for="team_facebook" > <?php _e('Facebook Profile', 'crunchpress'); ?> </h3>

                        </li>               

                        <li class="panel-input">

                            <input type="text" name="team_facebook" id="team_facebook" value="<?php if($team_facebook <> ''){echo $team_facebook;};?>" />

                        </li>

                        <p><?php _e('Please Enter Url for social profile.', 'crunchpress'); ?></p>

                    </ul>                   

                </div>

                <div class="span3">

                    <ul class="panel-body recipe_class">

                        <li class="panel-title">

                            <h3 for="team_linkedin" > <?php _e('Linked In Profile', 'crunchpress'); ?> </h3>

                        </li>               

                        <li class="panel-input">

                            <input type="text" name="team_linkedin" id="team_linkedin" value="<?php if($team_linkedin <> ''){echo $team_linkedin;};?>" />

                        </li>

                        <p><?php _e('Please Enter Url for social profile.', 'crunchpress'); ?></p>

                    </ul>   

                </div>

                <div class="span3">

                    <ul class="panel-body recipe_class">

                        <li class="panel-title">

                            <h3 for="team_twitter" > <?php _e('Twitter Profile', 'crunchpress'); ?> </h3>

                        </li>               

                        <li class="panel-input">

                            <input type="text" name="team_twitter" id="team_twitter" value="<?php if($team_twitter <> ''){echo $team_twitter;};?>" />

                        </li>

                        <p><?php _e('Please Enter Url for social profile.', 'crunchpress'); ?></p>

                    </ul>                       

                </div>

            </div>                      

            <input type="hidden" name="team_submit" value="teams"/>

            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>  

    </div>

    <?php }



    public function save_team_option_meta($post_id){



        $team_social = '';

        $sidebars = '';

        $right_sidebar_team = '';

        $left_sidebar_team = '';

        $team_facebook = '';

        $team_linkedin = '';

        $team_twitter = '';



        foreach($_REQUEST as $keys=>$values){

            $$keys = $values;

        }



        if(defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;



            if(isset($team_submit) AND $team_submit == 'teams'){

                $new_data = '<team_detail>';

                $new_data = $new_data . function_library::create_xml_tag('team_social',$team_social);

                $new_data = $new_data . function_library::create_xml_tag('sidebar_team',$sidebars);

                $new_data = $new_data . function_library::create_xml_tag('right_sidebar_team',$right_sidebar_team);

                $new_data = $new_data . function_library::create_xml_tag('left_sidebar_team',$left_sidebar_team);

                $new_data = $new_data . function_library::create_xml_tag('team_designation',$team_designation);

                $new_data = $new_data . function_library::create_xml_tag('team_facebook',$team_facebook);

                $new_data = $new_data . function_library::create_xml_tag('team_linkedin',$team_linkedin);

                $new_data = $new_data . function_library::create_xml_tag('team_twitter',$team_twitter);

                $new_data = $new_data . '</team_detail>';

        //Saving Sidebar and Social Sharing Settings as XML

        $old_data = get_post_meta($post_id, 'team_detail_xml',true);

        function_library::save_meta_data($post_id, $new_data, $old_data, 'team_detail_xml');



        }

    }



    // Print Event item

function print_team_item($item_xml){



    wp_reset_query();

    global $paged,$sidebar,$team_div_size_num_class,$post,$counter;



    if(empty($paged)){

        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; 

    }



    $category = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'category');

    // get the blog meta value      

    $header = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'header');

    $num_fetch = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'num-fetch');

    $num_excerpt = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'num_excerpt');



    if($category == '0'){

        //Post Query

        query_posts(

            array( 

            'post_type' => 'team',

            'posts_per_page' => $num_fetch,

            'paged' =>  $paged,

            'orderby' => 'slug',

            'order' => 'ASC' )

        );

    }else{

        //Post Query

        query_posts(

            array( 

            'post_type' => 'team',

            'posts_per_page' => $num_fetch,

            'paged'         =>  $paged,

            'tax_query' => array(

                array(

                    'taxonomy' => 'team-category',

                    'terms' => $category,

                    'field' => 'term_id',

                )

            ),

            'orderby' => 'slug',

            'order' => 'ASC' )

        );

    }

    $counter_team = 0; ?>

            <div class="our-team team-member-box ">                 

                <?php

                //Print Header

                if(!empty($header)){

                    echo '<h2 class="h-style">' . $header . '</h2>';

                }

                echo '<ul class="gallery">';

                //Start loop

                while( have_posts() ){

                the_post(); 



                global $post;

                    //Team Detail Other Elements

                    $team_detail_xml = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'team_detail_xml', true);

                    if($team_detail_xml <> ''){

                        $cp_team_xml = new DOMDocument ();

                        $cp_team_xml->loadXML ( $team_detail_xml );

                        $team_designation = find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'team_designation');

                        $team_facebook = find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'team_facebook');

                        $team_linkedin = find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'team_linkedin');

                        $team_twitter = find_xml_value($cp_team_xml->documentElement,'team_twitter');

                    }

                    //Line Break After Every Four Elements

                    $first_class = '';

                    $clear_div = '';

                    if($counter_team % 4 == 0){$first_class = 'first'; $clear_div = '<div class="clear"></div>';}else{}$counter_team++;?> 

                    <?php echo $clear_div;?>

                    <li class="span3 <?php echo $first_class;?>">

                        <?php

                        //Thumbnail for Team Members

                        $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

                        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id , array(350,350) ); 

                        $thumbnail_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id , 'full' );

                        ?>

                        <div class="team-box">

                          <div class="frame">

                            <div class="caption"><a data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" class="zoom" href="<?php echo $thumbnail_img[0]?>" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></div>



                                <?php 

                                if($thumbnail[1].'x'.$thumbnail[2] == '350x350'){ ?>

                                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(350,350));?>

                                <?php }?>

                            </div>



                          <div class="text">

                            <h4><a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_title();?></a></h4>

                            <?php if($team_designation <> ''){ ?><strong class="title"><?php echo $team_designation;?></strong><?php }?>

                            <p><?php echo mb_substr(get_the_content(),0,$num_excerpt);?> </p>

                            <div class="team-box-social">

                               <ul>

                                <?php if(isset($team_facebook) AND $team_facebook <> ''){?>

                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $team_facebook;?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>

                                <?php }?>

                                <?php if(isset($team_twitter) AND $team_twitter <> ''){?>

                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $team_twitter;?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>

                                <?php }?>

                                <?php if(isset($team_linkedin) AND $team_linkedin <> ''){?>

                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $team_linkedin;?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>

                                <?php }?>

                              </ul>

                            </div>

                          </div>

                        </div>      

                    </li>

                <?php  }?>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <?php



}// End Team Function for Frontend  





}
```

}

Comment: That is a lot of code...

Comment: i have no idea what is pertinent to this problem on the page and what isn't. so I just pasted the entire page, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your team members are likely a custom post type in WordPress.  If so, you should be able to use the **Simple Custom Post Order plugin** and drag/drop your team members in any order you want. https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/